# Kubernetes REST API - Create deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I was looking at the kubernetes API endpoints listed [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/operations/). Im trying to create a deployment which can be run from the terminal using `kubectl ru CLUSTER-NAME IMAGE-NAME PORT`. However I cant seem to find any endpoint for this command in the link I posted above. I can create a node using `curl POST /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods` and then delete using the `curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/node-name` where node name HAS to be a single node  (if there are 100 nodes, each should be done individually). **Is there an api endpoint for creating and deleting deployments??**

Answer (score 6):

To make it easier to eliminate fields or restructure resource representations, Kubernetes supports multiple API versions, each at a different API path, such as `/api/v1` or `/apis/extensions/v1beta1` and to extend the Kubernetes API,  API groups is implemented.

Currently there are several API groups in use:

- the `core` (oftentimes called `legacy`, due to not having explicit group name) group, which is at REST path `/api/v1` and is not specified as part of the apiVersion field, e.g. `apiVersion: v1`.
- the `named groups` are at REST path `/apis/$GROUP_NAME/$VERSION`, and use `apiVersion: $GROUP_NAME/$VERSION` (e.g. `apiVersion: batch/v1`). Full list of supported API groups can be seen in [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/).

To manage extensions resources such as `Ingress`, `Deployments`, and `ReplicaSets` refer to `Extensions API` [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/operations/).

As described in the reference, to create a Deployment:

`POST /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments`

Answer (score 5):

I debugged this by running `kubectl` with verbose logging: `kubectl --v=9 update -f dev_inventory.yaml`.

It showed the use of an API call like this one:

`curl -i http://localhost:8001/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments`

Note that the first path element is `apis`, not the normal `api`. I don't know why it's like this, but the command above works.

Comment: Great twofer! I both learned the actual URL and how to learn more about kubectl in the future!

Answer (score 2):

The Kubernetes [Rest Api documentation](http://kubernetes.io/kubernetes/third_party/swagger-ui/#/) is quite sophisticated but unfortunately the deployment documentation is missing. 
Since the Rest schema is identical to other resources you can figure out the rest calls:

GET retrieve a deployment by name:

- curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${KEY}" ${API_URL}/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/${namespace}/deployments/${NAME}

POST create a new deployment

- curl -X POST -d @deployment-definition.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${KEY}" ${API_URL}/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/${namespace}/deployments

You should be able to use the calls right away when you provide the placeholder for your

- API key ${KEY}
- API url ${API_URL}
- Deployment name ${NAME}
- Namespace ${namespace}

Comment: I am using https://github.com/abonas/kubeclient and neither `get_deployments` nor `get_deployment` are working. The reported error is `KubeException (the server could not find the requested resource)`. I am constructing the API client like this: `Kubeclient::Client.new 'http://localhost:8001/api/', 'extensions/v1beta1'`.

Answer (score 2):

I might be too late to help in this question, but here is what I tried on v1.9 to deploy a StatefulSet:

```
curl -kL -XPOST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer <*token*>" --data @statefulset.json \
 https://<*ip*>:6443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/eng-pst/statefulsets
```

I converted the statefulset.yaml to json cause I saw the data format when api was doing the POST was in json.

I ran this command to find out the API call i need to make for my k8s object:

```
kubectl --v=10 apply -f statefulset.yaml
```

(might not need a v=10 level but I wanted to as much info as I could)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the analogous URL?

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/deployment/deployment-name
```

Comment: Yep. Did. get a `could not find a requested resource`

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason you're not using `kubectl` ?

Comment: Also, it seems like deployments were introduced in `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`, which is why you might not be able to access them with a `v1` endpoint.

Comment: @Beginner http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/
Take special look at the YAML for creating a deployment, like [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/nginx-deployment.yaml)

Comment: I know how to use the `kubectl` command  to work with deployments. Wanted to see if they have API endpoints for it which they dont. The `v1beta1` has bugs. FOr example if you delete a deployment using the API endpoint the corresponding pods are still alive.

Comment: `curl http://localhost:8001/api/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments` returns 404. `curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods` works fine.